# Tools & Practices for Test Environments?

Tags: test-data, test-engineering

Just been given responsibility for managing the companies Non Production Environments and Data i.e. Development & Test Environments. What tools and practices are can you recommend?

Yodel

FYI I will be managing Hundreds of Systems, Thousands of Servers.

Comment: This is a pretty big question. What has the company got in place now? What's your role there? Is there a team for environment management? What have you considered already? Have you been given a budget? How are the hundreds of systems managed currently? Why do you have thousands of servers? I imagine this question hypothetical... but, as it stands, we're unable to give you a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools on the market that specifically focus on Test Environments & Test Data. A good one (disclaimer - whom I currently work for) is **Enov8** Ref: [enov8](https://www.enov8.com). Our clients tend to be at the scale you define (if not bigger). IMHO Small clients may quite easily get away with spreadsheets, however given enov8 can be downloaded for free, that approach is also questionable.

Regarding practices, you may want to look at this "Test Environment Anti Patterns" [article](https://dzone.com/articles/agile-and-run-run-stop-or-test-environments-anti-p) or the [EMMi](https://www.enov8.com/resources/#EMMI) (Environment Management Maturity Index).

Reach out if you want more ideas.

Jane

Answer (score 0):

For Test Environments you may find TEMDOT useful.

Specifically: 
+ [TEM-Process](https://testenvironmentmanagement.com/tem-process/)
+ [TEM Tools](https://testenvironmentmanagement.com/tem-tools/)

Willow

Answer (score 0):

### Tools and practices for test environments and data.

#### The list is (too) long

aws, selenium, bdd, tdd, agile, scrum, kanban, jira, pivotal tracker, ado, git, sql, redis, mongo, etc.

You need to give much more details on company and product in order to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thousands of servers should be as if just one.
Hardware configuration should versioned.

Study a bit about [Infrastructure as Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) and [Containers](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container).